# TextJoin Remove Duplicates but with an If Function filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin

I am using the new `TextJoin` function with a `Match` and a `IF` function as a filter. The statement works for the most part, but for every row that dos not meet the filter requirement it returns a "False". Is there a way to filter and not get a bunch of "False" returns but just the correct ones?

Here is my Formula:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(";",,IF(E5:E211="Austin",IF(MATCH(D5:D211,D5:D211,0)=ROW(E5:E211)-ROW(E5)+1,D5:D211,"")))}
```

It finds all the correct items, but Adds the `False`s' too.

Comment: what version of excel do you have?

Comment: 2016 Office 365

Comment: Excel 2016 and Office 365 are two different versions with different formulas for find Unique items.  Do you have an Office 365 subscription?

Comment: You are missing a `""` for the first `IF`, so replace the last part of your formula `)))` with `),""))`.  That said, depending on the answer to Scotts' question there may be a better way.  Update your Q with some sample data and expected results

Comment: Yes I have Excel for Office 365 ProPlus

Comment: Chris's Answer took care of it! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with an Office 365 subscription we can use the dynamic array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",,UNIQUE(FILTER(D:D,E:E="Austin")))
```